# svm KKT condition violation that alpha choice in SMO

Tags: svm

when I was read the paper about SMO　for SVM.
[John C. Platt paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-98-14.pdf)

choosing the alpha which violated KKT condition is very confusing me. I do not very understand the code as below.

```
if ((r2 < -tol && alph2 < C) || (r2 > tol && alph2 > 0))
```

why does it choose r2 < -tol when alph2 < C, not r2 < tol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation $12$ of the paper states the $KKT$ condition:

\begin{align}
\alpha_i = 0 &\iff y_iu_i\geq1 \\
0<\alpha_i < C &\iff y_iu_i = 1 \\
\alpha_i = C &\iff y_iu_i \le 1
\end{align}

Hence if $\alpha_i < C$, we are suppose to have $y_iu_i \geq 1$.

To violate $y_iu_i \geq 1$ means $y_iu_i < 1$,

$$y_iu_i < 1 = y_i^2$$

is equivalent to

$$y_i(u_i-y_i ) < 0$$

Using the notation of the paper, it is $r_2=y_i E_i < 0$.

Numerically, we consider $y_iE_i$ to be negative if it is smaller than $-\epsilon$ for some small positive number $\epsilon$.